# how send a class Instance to web service?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, serialization

I want to send a class instance to my Web Service(ASP.NET - C#).
How can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) enabled web service you need to first generate a client proxy by pointing [svcutil.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) (or [wsdl.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6(VS.80).aspx) if you are using .NET 2.0) to the WSDL that is exposed by the web service. You could also do this directly in Visual Studio ([Add Service Reference...](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/consuming-data-web-asmx-service.html)). This will generate the client proxy classes that will enable you to invoke service methods and pass them object instances they accept.

If this is not a SOAP web service you will need to provide more details.

Comment: Hımm,
Thanks.
Serialize is a solution for me?

Comment: Serialization is handled automatically by the generated client proxy classes, so that you don't need to worry about the plumbing.

Comment: My class is derived and isnt serialized.
I cant send class value to web servise.